# How to achieve something like this using React Native

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

How can i make a component like this:

[image: What I want]

I managed to do it until now:
[image: What I get]

Here's how my code looks like:

```
viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: color.bgColor,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        width: 100,
        height: '100%',
        top: '30%',
        transform: [{ scaleX: 4 }],
        zIndex: 1,
        borderTopEndRadius: 20,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
        borderTopRightRadius: 20
    },
```

Comment: Can you share what u did in the snack?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior no I cant make the sharp curves like the above picture

Answer (score 0):

It´s easier to use an image instead.
But you can try it using [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg)

The shape you're searching for may not be already made, so you can first learn how to make an rectangle and a circle, like as follow:

```js
import Svg, {
  Circle,
  Ellipse,
  G,
  Text,
  TSpan,
  TextPath,
  Path,
  Polygon,
  Polyline,
  Line,
  Rect,
  Use,
  Image,
  Symbol,
  Defs,
  LinearGradient,
  RadialGradient,
  Stop,
  ClipPath,
  Pattern,
  Mask,
} from 'react-native-svg';

/* Use this if you are using Expo
import * as Svg from 'react-native-svg';
const { Circle, Rect } = Svg;
*/

import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class SvgExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
          StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
          { alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' },
        ]}
      >
        <Svg height="50%" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <Circle
            cx="50"
            cy="50"
            r="45"
            stroke="blue"
            strokeWidth="2.5"
            fill="green"
          />
          <Rect
            x="15"
            y="15"
            width="70"
            height="70"
            stroke="red"
            strokeWidth="2"
            fill="yellow"
          />
        </Svg>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here´s the output:

[image]

What you're searching for may be quite longer and requires many precise configurations of:

`position`

`colors`

`borders`

and etc...

But it can be made with react-native-svg, if you dont want to use an image.